# change text on a hyperlink in a datalist

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, datalist

I'm trying to bind a column from a SQL code that i have written to all hyperlinks in a datalist. This should be really simple but I'm getting the error

> DataBinding: 'System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal' does not contain
>   a property with the name 'NumberOfComments'.

Well I'm pretty sure the column exist but in this case it's created by a function maybe that has something to do with it. When I run the SQL code i get the values I should.

The hyperlink

```
            <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkComment" runat="server" 
                NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("ID", "~/Default.aspx?ID={0}") %>' 
                Text='<%# Eval("NumberOfComments") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
```

The SQLDataSource

```
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsNews" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ASPNETDBConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT        News.ID, News.Topic, News.Text, News.PostTime, aspnet_Users.UserName, &quot;NumberOfComments&quot; = dbo.fnNumberOfCommentOnNews(News.ID)
FROM            News INNER JOIN
                         aspnet_Users ON News.UserId = aspnet_Users.UserId
WHERE        (News.ID = ISNULL(@ID, News.ID))
ORDER BY News.PostTime DESC ">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:QueryStringParameter DbType="Guid" Name="ID" QueryStringField="ID" DefaultValue="" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have "`&quot;`" surrounding NumberOfComments FieldName?

Try pasting the select command into SSMS (SQL Server Mgmt studio) and you should most definitely get an incorrect syntax error. If you drop those quot html code you will still be able to reference and bind to that column.

Comment: You can't write " in the ConnectionString that's why i use them but this has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: I am not referring to the ConnectionString. Unless this is a result of a copy paste, i believe that replacing the html code &quot; with a single quot surrounding NumberOfComments in the Select Command  should fix the issue. Did you check the actual SQL statement being sent to SQL server? (You can do that in Sql Server Management Studio   Profiler . Tools -> Sql Server Profiler)

Comment: try replacing the NavigateUrl assignment NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("~/Default.aspx?ID={0}", Eval("ID"))